# Jinja append in same line after if-else

Tags: jinja2

I have the following piece of HTML:

```html
<li style="margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px">Vendor accounts:</li>
{% if fact_foundVendorList is defined and fact_foundVendorList|length > 0 %}
   {% for vendor in fact_foundVendorList %}
      <ul>
         <li style="margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px">{{ vendor }}</li>
      </ul>
   {% endfor %}
{%- else -%}
No accounts were found for the user
{%- endif -%}
```

When the if `fact_foundVendorList` returns to be false, it will look like this:

```
* Vendor accounts:
    No vendor accounts were found for the user
```

Otherwise, it would like something like:

```
 * Vendor accounts:
    * account1
    * account2
```

I only want to change the `false` output. In case it's false I want to have the message in the same line as the "vendor accounts" line. So it should look like this:

```
* Vendor accounts: No accounts were found for the user.
```

I thought adding the following `%- -%` would work, but I think I need something else

```
{%- else -%}
No accounts were found for the user
{%- endif -%}
```

I saw various related solutions online but couldn't apply it to my case without breaking the structure of the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags in my template. It's a long document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here lies on the fact that you will have to have the `No accounts were found for the user` inside the `<li>` containing `Vendor accounts:`, otherwise it won't be on the same line, as you  want your list to be of the default `display: list-item` type.

What you can do, then, is to create a variable with the condition, then use it to display the message.

```html
{% set has_account = fact_foundVendorList | default([]) | length > 0 %}

<li style="margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px">
  Vendor accounts: {% if not has_account %}No accounts were found for the user{% endif %}
</li>
{% for vendor in fact_foundVendorList | default([]) %}
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-bottom: 3px; margin-top: 3px">{{ vendor }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

***Note that**: by defining a [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) value to an empty list, you do not need to assert if the list is defined for the `length` filter to be able to give you the correct information*